# Laravel push collection to empty array

Tags: laravel

Hey I have a query where I'm getting a site, once i get the site i manually setAttribute a key `companies` and its value is `[]`, I then want push multiple arrays inside the companies empty array one at a time based on their condition if the condition is true the array will be pushed if not it won't be pushed. In this case the second if statement override the data of first statement, i want to keep both data. i tried using `put()` function but it throws an error `Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::put does not exist.`

can anyone please help me out. thanks

**Code:**

```
        $site =  CpdApi::where('id', $admin->id)->get();
        
        $allData = collect([$site->first()->setAttribute('companies', [])]);
        
        if(count($abcApiData))
        {
            $allData->first()->companies = $abcApiCompanies;
        }
        
        if(count($localStandardCompaniesQuery))
        {
            $allData->first()->companies = $localStandardCompaniesQuery->pluck('companies');
        }
        
        return $allData;
```

**Data Structure of Site:**

```
[
    {
        "id": 7,
        "title": "Just Testing",
        "email": "testing@testing.co.uk",
    }
]
```

**Data Structure of abcAPIData and localStandardCompaniesQuery:**

```
[
    {
        "comp_id": 94,
        "comp_title": "Loreum Ipseum 01",
    },
    {
        "comp_id": 245,
        "comp_title": "Loreum Ipseum 02",
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so i've figured it out on my own. This is what i did, if anyone has a better option please post you answer. Thankyou.

```
$site =  CpdApi::where('id', $admin->id)->get();
            
$companies = collect([]);
            
if(count($localAdvanceCompaniesQuery))
{
    $companies = $companies->merge($localAdvanceCompaniesQuery->pluck('companies'));
}
            
if(count($localStandardCompaniesQuery))
{
    $companies = $companies->merge($localStandardCompaniesQuery->pluck('companies'));
}
            
if(count($mapleApiData))
{
    $companies = $companies->merge($mapleApiCompaniesQuery->pluck('companies'));
}
            
if(count($atpApiData))
{
    $companies = $companies->merge($atpApiCompaniesQuery->pluck('companies'));
}
            
$companiesFlattened = $companies->collapse();
$allData = collect([$site->first()->setAttribute('companies', $companiesFlattened)]);
```